# matching number in PHP simpletest webtestcase assert

Tags: php, regex, unit-testing, simpletest

I am writing a PHP simpletest webtestcase. The following assert does not work.

```
$this->assertPattern('"serverTime":\d+');
```

for the page response

> Blah Bla "serverTime":1447147314 ,Bla Bla

However when I test the regex in an online tool it works. I need to assert that the response contains a string "serverTime":<10digitnumber>

Comment: What was the question actually? Can you show your expected result?

Comment: Expected result is to assert that serverTime key exists in the response json with a 10 digit epoc time.

Answer (score 0):

The function syntax is `assertPattern($regexp, $x)`.

That means: fail, unless the regex `$regexp` matches `$x`.

The regexp you are looking for is: `#\"serverTime\":(\d+){10}#`.

The whole function for SimpleTest:

```
    public function testPattern()
    {
        $string = 'Blah Bla "serverTime":1447147314 ,Bla Bla';

        $this->assertPattern('#\"serverTime\":(\d+){10}#', $string);
    }
```